# All the Relative path references in wsdl files are not working in TIBCO BW 5. And getting the error : The following reference is no longer valid

Tags: wsdl, tibco-business-works, tibco-designer

All the Relative path references in wsdl files are not working in TIBCO BW 5.  And getting the error:

> The following reference is no longer valid: ../../../Base/.

Can anyone please verify this suggest me the solution.

Comment: From the WSDL file are the references located at the proper relative location ?

Comment: @EmmanuelM - The reference paths and files are all valid.  We are using BW 5.12, it is validation throwing error for a simple schema mapping into WSDL message.

Answer (score 0):

I see there is an hotfix for BW 5.12 that might help :

BW-16430
Relative path references failed to validate after upgrading to TIBCO
ActiveMatrix BusinessWorks 5.12.0.

I would recommend installing latest HF for BW 5.12.

Comment: @Emmanual : Thanks for the solution, now the validation is good.

Comment: @R You are welcome please confirm my answer as useful